# Can't display image from backend having this error of "Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed."

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display the image from backend folder but I receive this error of "Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.". I'm using multer to upload all the images. I can you please help me why this is happening. Thanks!

Image path:
http://localhost:5000/server/public/uploads/60cb54ab4b3e6439c0c09bc7/item/burger.png

Folder Structure

[image]

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const __dirname = path.resolve('..');

app.use('/public/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/public/uploads'));
```

Frontend

```
{item &&
              item.items.map((item, index) => (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className='w-2/12 border rounded-lg customBlackLighter-light'
                >
                  <img
                    className='w-full'
                    src={URL.createObjectURL(item.uploads)}
                    alt={item.title}
                  />
                  <div className='px-6 py-4 flex flex-col'>
                    <h2 className='text-md text-center font-bold mb-2'>
                      {item.title}
                    </h2>
                    <p className='text-customBlackLighter-dark text-toolTipTitle  justify-center text-center flex'>
                      {item.description}
                    </p>
                    <p className='text-customRed text-sm justify-center text-center flex pt-6'>
                      {item.price}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className='px-6 pt-4 pb-2'>
                    <span className='inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2'>
                      #{item.tags}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class='my-8'>
                    <Button
                      type='button'
                      caption='Edit dish'
                      className='bg-customRed w-2/3 hover:bg-customRed-dark flex justify-center mx-auto'
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
```

Output:

[image]